# Angle between two circles (which angle to be considered?)

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

The question goes like:

> Find the angle of intersection of 2 circles
> S:$x^2+y^2-4x+6y+11=0$ and S': $x^2+y^2-2x+8y+13=0$...

I used the formula $$\cos x = \frac{\vert r_1^2+r_2^2-d^2\vert}{2r_1r_2}$$
Where $r_1,\;r_2$ are the radii of the circles and $d$ is the distance between the centers.
I got the answer as $\cos x = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right|$ which is $45°$.
But the answer sheet says $135°$.
Should I take the positive or negative value of cos here? How do I know which one to take in general?

Comment: negative if the answer is $135°$

Comment: Use the angle that’s external to both circles.

Answer (score 1):

The angle between the two circles is the angle formed by the tangents in an intersection point. Look [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AngleOfIntersectionOfTwoCircles/) and the image below

hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Is there a general way to identify this angle because I won't have a graph like this in a test.

Comment: is there a way to identify this angle without a graph?

Comment: @Mahadev I have googled a little and looks like nobody cares if it is the acute or the obtuse one. The concept, indeed, is useful to define orthogonal circles, where the angle is $90°$ without ambiguity. As a teacher I had accepted $45°$ and $135°$ as equivalent answers.

Comment: Thanks for the help